# Is the PMD Eclipse Plugin Open Source?

Tags: pmd

Is the PMD *Eclipse Plugin* Open Source? And if yes, where is the source please?

I know that PMD is open source and the code can be found here: http://sourceforge.net/projects/pmd/files/pmd/

And that other plugins like Netbeans have open source code here:  http://sourceforge.net/projects/pmd/files/pmd-netbeans/pmd-netbeans-2.2.7/

But the eclipse plugin page does not seem to have source code available: http://sourceforge.net/projects/pmd/files/pmd-eclipse/3.2.6/

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like the source code is available [here](https://github.com/acanda/eclipse-pmd/), in the Github project page.

PMD eclipse plugin is released with a

> PMD's BSD-style license

available in the binary distribution

Answer (score -2):

You can found PMD source code at https://github.com/pmd/pmd

You can also scroll down and find PMD website link to check authenticity.

You can edit PMD rules in grammar using this link
https://github.com/pmd/pmd/blob/master/pmd-java/etc/grammar/Java.jjt